# If I don't want cluster marker on here map, what shoud I do ? Please

Tags: android

I'm trying show all my map makers on Here maps, but I don't want cluster them to a number, like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aa0k.jpg). I used Here maps app, markers not clustered [Here Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P4fp.jpg). 
What should I do ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#custom).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm working with Here maps, not Google Maps :p. Thank for your help !

Comment: @LongNgôAnh oops, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ClusterLayer class.

```
ClusterLayer cl = new ClusterLayer();
```

If you want to customize the image use their ImageClusterStyle & ClusterTheme.

```
ImageClusterStyle imageCluster = new ImageClusterStyle(img);
ClusterTheme theme = new ClusterTheme();
theme.setStyleForDensityRange(2, 9, imageCluster);
cl.setTheme(theme);
```